# How to use SOLR copyField directive to use for muiple fields

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I have a rather simple SOLR structure, that hold three different fields:

id, text and tags

in the `schema.xml` I set the following

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
<copyField source="tags" dest="text"/>
```

However, when I search a word that only appears as a tag, then the document is not found.

My question here is: does copyField happen before any analyzer runs (index and query) as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) or just before the query analyzer?

---

**EDIT**

the analyzer def:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />              
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />              
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and the field-type definitions (they are pretty much as the default configs):

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

and last the field definitions:

```
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="tags" type="text" indexed="false" stored="false" />
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
<copyField source="tags" dest="text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`copyField` is invoked before any analysis happens (which is kind of the point of having copy fields - they allow you to process the same content in multiple ways).

But this copying *only* happens when you're indexing. If you're querying `tags`, you won't be getting hits in `text` at the same time. However, if you've submitted a value for `tags`, it'll be added as a value in the `text` field as well - and the only processing that takes place is the one defined for `text`.